# How to show react-native-maps in specific radius

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react-native project where I should show items on Google maps in a specific radius. So if I search a location in 25 mile radius I should see map zoomed to fit all items in 25 miles. Then user can automatically zoom in/out and radius will change. Basically I need a formula to convert radius in miles to latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta. Thanks

Comment: Set Zoom property to your requirement.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib there is no such property, zoom should be calculated by latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/705#issuecomment-255376615

Comment: Unfortunately there is no connection between radius and latitude/longitude deltas